# How do you spy on structuredClone() using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, spying

I want to spy on the [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) method and mock its implementation because when running Jest tests, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: structuredClone is not defined

I've tried both spying and mocking as below, but I got errors with both.

```
jest
  .spyOn(global, 'structuredClone')
  .mockImplementation((value) => cloneDeep(value));
```

> Cannot spy the structuredClone property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

```
jest.mock('global.structuredClone', () =>
  jest.fn().mockImplementation((value) => cloneDeep(value))
);
```

> Cannot find module 'structuredClone' from ...

How can I mock the implementation using Jest?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
const mockStructuredClone = jest.fn();
global.structuredClone = () => mockStructuredClone();

it('should work', () => {
  mockStructuredClone.mockReturnValue({ test: 42 });
```